# Post parameter removed but reappear after Ajax call

Tags: ajax, symfony

I am building a quiz. On button click for each answer, an ajax function is called and return a Json Response that reload the current route in order to display the next question or the results of the quiz if ended.

The user is able to retry a new quiz if he failed, and can retry until he succeed.
For that, he clicks on a submit input form on the results page.

My issue is that the first time the results must be displayed everything is okay. I click on the submit retry input to restart a new form. I remove the 'retry' post parameter. And still, it comes back after the next ajax call.

Is somebody able to explain me what is happening and how to remove the post parameter for good ?

My controller :

```
class ExamController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Return ExamTaker views.
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // get current user
        $user = $this->getUser();

        // get manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // get user stats service
        $stats = $this->get('user.stats');

        /*************************************/
        /* Get usefull datas                 */
        /*************************************/
        // get current module group
        $module_group = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ModuleGroup')->findOneById($id);

        // check if module group taker exists
        $module_group_taker = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('UserBundle:ModuleGroupTaker')->findOneBy(['user' => $user, 'module_group' => $module_group]);

        // check if an exam taker is not completed yet
        $current_exam_taker = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamTaker')->findOneBy(['user' => $user, 'module_group' => $module_group, 'completed' => null]);

        // check if exam is already succeed
        $exam_certif_taker = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamCertificationTaker')->findOneBy(['user' => $user, 'module_group' => $module_group]);

        // check if an exam is in correction state
        $exam_taker_in_correction = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamTaker')->getExamInCorrection($user, $module_group);

        /**************************************/
        /* Security : access not allowed to   */
        /* expired supervisor                 */
        /**************************************/
        $ac = $this->get('security.authorization_checker');

        if (($ac->isGranted('ROLE_SUPERVISOR') || $ac->isGranted('ROLE_MANAGER')) && $user->getExpiration()->format('YmdHis') < date('YmdHis')) {
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
        }

        /********************************************/
        /* if user already succeed with score 20/20 */
        /********************************************/
        if ($exam_certif_taker && 20 == $exam_certif_taker->getExamTaker()->getScore()) {
            dump('1');

            // return results view
            return $this->render('UserBundle:exam:examresults.html.twig', [
                'exam'          => $exam_certif_taker->getExamTaker(),
                'exam_certif'   => $exam_certif_taker,
                'certification' => $user->getCertification(),
            ]);
        }

        /********************************************/
        /* if user already succeed with less than   */
        /* 20/20 and wants to retry                 */
        /********************************************/
        elseif ($exam_certif_taker && 1 == $exam_certif_taker->getTries() && $request->request->get('retry') && !$user->getCertification()) {
            dump('2');
            $request->request->remove('retry');
            $request->request->setContent(null);
            $exam_taker_in_correction->setCorrected(new \DateTime());
            $exam_taker    = $this->createNewExamTaker($user, $module_group);
            $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(1, $exam_taker);

            return $this->render('UserBundle:exam:exam.html.twig', [
                'size'       => \count($exam_taker->getQuestions()),
                'title'      => $module_group->getTitle(),
                'question'   => $next_question,
                'color'      => $module_group->getColor(),
                'exam_taker' => $exam_taker,
            ]);
        }

        /********************************************/
        /* if user already succeed with less than   */
        /* 20/20 and an exam taker is not completed */
        /********************************************/
        elseif ($exam_certif_taker && $current_exam_taker) {
            dump('3');
            $next_exam_answer_taker = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamAnswerTaker')->findOneBy(['exam' => $current_exam_taker, 'answer' => null]);
            $next_question          = $next_exam_answer_taker->getQuestion();

            return $this->render('UserBundle:exam:exam.html.twig', [
                'size'       => \count($current_exam_taker->getQuestions()),
                'title'      => $module_group->getTitle(),
                'question'   => $next_question,
                'color'      => $module_group->getColor(),
                'exam_taker' => $current_exam_taker,
            ]);
        }

        /********************************************/
        /* for all other cases user has succeed     */
        /* return results                           */
        /********************************************/
        elseif ($exam_certif_taker) {
            dump('4');

            // return results view
            return $this->render('UserBundle:exam:examresults.html.twig', [
                'exam'          => $exam_certif_taker->getExamTaker(),
                'exam_certif'   => $exam_certif_taker,
                'certification' => $user->getCertification(),
            ]);
        }

        /********************************************/
        /* if user failed and wants to retry        */
        /********************************************/
        elseif ($exam_taker_in_correction && $request->request->get('retry')) {
            dump('5');
            $request->request->remove('retry');
            $exam_taker_in_correction->setCorrected(new \DateTime());
            $exam_taker    = $this->createNewExamTaker($user, $module_group);
            $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(1, $exam_taker);

            return $this->render('UserBundle:exam:exam.html.twig', [
                'size'       => \count($exam_taker->getQuestions()),
                'title'      => $module_group->getTitle(),
                'question'   => $next_question,
                'color'      => $module_group->getColor(),
                'exam_taker' => $exam_taker,
            ]);
        }

        /********************************************/
        /* if user failed and didn't ask to retry   */
        /********************************************/
        elseif ($exam_taker_in_correction) {
            dump('6');

            // return results view
            return $this->render('UserBundle:exam:examresults.html.twig', [
                'exam'          => $exam_taker_in_correction,
                'exam_certif'   => false,
                'certification' => false,
            ]);
        }

        /********************************************/
        /* if an exam is not completed yet          */
        /********************************************/
        elseif ($current_exam_taker) {
            dump('7');
            $next_exam_answer_taker = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamAnswerTaker')->findOneBy(['exam' => $current_exam_taker, 'answer' => null]);
            $next_question          = $next_exam_answer_taker->getQuestion();

            return $this->render('UserBundle:exam:exam.html.twig', [
                'size'       => \count($current_exam_taker->getQuestions()),
                'title'      => $module_group->getTitle(),
                'question'   => $next_question,
                'color'      => $module_group->getColor(),
                'exam_taker' => $current_exam_taker,
            ]);
        }

        /********************************************/
        /* all other cases, create a new exam taker */
        /********************************************/
        else {
            dump('8');
            $exam_taker    = $this->createNewExamTaker($user, $module_group);
            $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(1, $exam_taker);

            return $this->render('UserBundle:exam:exam.html.twig', [
                'size'       => \count($exam_taker->getQuestions()),
                'title'      => $module_group->getTitle(),
                'question'   => $next_question,
                'color'      => $module_group->getColor(),
                'exam_taker' => $exam_taker,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * ajax function to save current answer
     * and return either results or next question.
     */
    public function saveAction(Request $request)
    {
        //Prepare usefull datas
        $em                  = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $exam_taker_id       = $request->request->get('exam_taker_id');
        $current_question_id = $request->request->get('question_id');
        $answer_id           = $request->request->get('answer_id');
        $exam_taker          = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamTaker')->findOneById($exam_taker_id);
        $current_question    = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamQuestion')->findOneById($current_question_id);
        $exam_answer         = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamAnswer')->findOneById($answer_id);
        $exam_answer_taker   = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamAnswerTaker')->findOneBy(['exam' => $exam_taker, 'question' => $current_question]);
        $level               = $current_question->getLevel();
        $next_question       = false;
        $module_group        = $exam_taker->getModuleGroup();
        $user                = $exam_taker->getUser();

        //save answer taker
        $exam_answer_taker->setAnswer($exam_answer);
        $em->flush();

        // get array of exam taker questions already displayed
        $exam_taker_questions = $exam_taker->getQuestions();
        $count_questions      = \count($exam_taker_questions);

        // Check if last answer is good
        $good_answer                                                       = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamAnswer')->findOneBy(['question' => $current_question, 'correct' => true]);
        ($good_answer === $exam_answer_taker->getAnswer()) ? $check_answer = true : $check_answer = false;

        // update correct var
        if ($check_answer) {
            $exam_answer_taker->setCorrect(1);
        } else {
            $exam_answer_taker->setCorrect(0);
        }

        // Update last answer given
        $em->flush();

        // count answers group by level
        $array_answers = [
            '1' => ['success' => 0, 'fail' => 0],
            '2' => ['success' => 0, 'fail' => 0],
            '3' => ['success' => 0, 'fail' => 0],
            '4' => ['success' => 0, 'fail' => 0],
            '5' => ['success' => 0, 'fail' => 0],
        ];

        foreach ($exam_taker->getAnswers() as $answer) {
            if ($answer->getCorrect()) {
                switch ($answer->getQuestion()->getLevel()) {
                    case '1':
                        ++$array_answers['1']['success'];
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        ++$array_answers['2']['success'];
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        ++$array_answers['3']['success'];
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        ++$array_answers['4']['success'];
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        ++$array_answers['5']['success'];
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                switch ($answer->getQuestion()->getLevel()) {
                    case '1':
                        ++$array_answers['1']['fail'];
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        ++$array_answers['2']['fail'];
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        ++$array_answers['3']['fail'];
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        ++$array_answers['4']['fail'];
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        ++$array_answers['5']['fail'];
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        // if count questions is 20
        if (20 == $count_questions) {
            // set completed to end current exam
            $exam_taker->setCompleted(new \DateTime());

            // check if good answer to the current question
            if ($check_answer) {
                // set score depending on successes
                if (3 == $array_answers['5']['success']) { // if 3 success level 5, set score to 20
                    $exam_taker->setScore(20);
                    $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                } elseif (3 == $array_answers['4']['success']) { // if 3 success level 4, set score to 16
                    $exam_taker->setScore(16);
                    $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                } elseif (3 == $array_answers['3']['success']) { // if 3 success level 3, set score to 14
                    $exam_taker->setScore(14);
                    $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                } elseif (3 == $array_answers['2']['success']) { // if success level 2, set score to 12
                    $exam_taker->setScore(12);
                    $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                } else {
                    $exam_taker->setScore(0);
                }
            } else {
                switch ($level) {
                    case 5:
                        if (2 == $array_answers['5']['fail']) { // if 2 fail level 5, set score to 16
                            $exam_taker->setScore(16);
                            $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                        } elseif (3 == $array_answers['4']['fail']) { // if 3 fail level 4, set score 14
                            $exam_taker->setScore(14);
                            $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                        } elseif (3 == $array_answers['3']['fail']) { // if 3 fail level 3, set score 12
                            $exam_taker->setScore(12);
                            $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                        } else {
                            $exam_taker->setScore(0);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        if (3 == $array_answers['4']['fail']) { // if 3 fail level 4, set score 14
                            $exam_taker->setScore(14);
                            $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                        } elseif (3 == $array_answers['3']['fail']) { // if 3 fail level 3, set score 12
                            $exam_taker->setScore(12);
                            $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                        } else {
                            $exam_taker->setScore(0);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        if (3 == $array_answers['3']['fail']) { // if 3 fail level 3, set score 12
                            $exam_taker->setScore(12);
                            $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                        } else {
                            $exam_taker->setScore(0);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        $exam_taker->setScore(0);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        $exam_taker->setScore(0);
                        break;
                }
            }
        } else { // if not 20 questions yet
            // check if good answer to the current question
            if ($check_answer) {
                if ((5 == $level) && (3 == $array_answers['5']['success'])) {
                    $exam_taker->setScore(20);
                    $exam_taker->setCompleted(new \DateTime());
                    $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                } elseif (5 == $level) {
                    $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(5, $exam_taker);
                } elseif (4 == $level) {
                    $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(5, $exam_taker);
                } elseif (3 == $level) {
                    $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(4, $exam_taker);
                } elseif (2 == $level) {
                    $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(3, $exam_taker);
                } elseif (1 == $level) {
                    $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(2, $exam_taker);
                }
            } else {
                switch ($level) {
                    case 5:
                        if (2 == $array_answers['5']['fail']) { // if 2 fail level 5, set score to 16
                            $exam_taker->setScore(16);
                            $exam_taker->setCompleted(new \DateTime());
                            $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                        } else {
                            $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(4, $exam_taker);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        if (3 == $array_answers['4']['fail']) { // if 3 fail level 4, set score to 14
                            $exam_taker->setScore(14);
                            $exam_taker->setCompleted(new \DateTime());
                            $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                        } else {
                            $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(3, $exam_taker);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        if (3 == $array_answers['3']['fail']) { // if 3 fail level 3, set score to 12
                            $exam_taker->setScore(12);
                            $exam_taker->setCompleted(new \DateTime());
                            $this->createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group);
                        } else {
                            $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(2, $exam_taker);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        if (4 == $array_answers['2']['fail']) { // if 4 fail level 2, stop exam
                            $exam_taker->setScore(0);
                            $exam_taker->setCompleted(new \DateTime());
                        } else {
                            $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(1, $exam_taker);
                        }
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if (5 == $array_answers['1']['fail']) { // if 5 fail level 1, stop exam
                            $exam_taker->setScore(0);
                            $exam_taker->setCompleted(new \DateTime());
                        } else {
                            $next_question = $this->prepareNextExamQuestion(1, $exam_taker);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        $em->flush();

        // return next question to continue the current exam
        return new JsonResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Add next question to current exam taker.
     */
    public function prepareNextExamQuestion($level, $exam_taker)
    {
        // get manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // prepare test questions random array
        // without questions already used
        if (\count($exam_taker->getQuestions()) > 0) {
            $questions_by_level = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamQuestion')->getUnusedQuestionByLevel($level, $exam_taker->getModuleGroup(), $exam_taker->getQuestions());
        } else {
            $questions_by_level = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamQuestion')->getUnusedQuestionByLevel1($level, $exam_taker->getModuleGroup());
        }

        // set a random question to display (the result is an array)
        $random_question_id = array_rand($questions_by_level, 1);
        $random_question    = $questions_by_level[$random_question_id];

        // add question to exam taker
        $exam_taker->addQuestion($random_question);
        $random_question->addExam($exam_taker);

        // create exam answer taker
        $exam_answer_taker = new ExamAnswerTaker();
        $exam_answer_taker->setExam($exam_taker);
        $exam_answer_taker->setQuestion($random_question);

        $exam_taker->addAnswer($exam_answer_taker);

        $em->persist($exam_answer_taker);
        $em->flush();

        return $random_question;
    }

    /**
     * create or update a new exam certification taker.
     */
    public function createNewExamCertificationTaker($exam_taker, $user, $module_group): void
    {
        // get manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        // check if exam certification taker already exists
        $exam_certif_taker = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:ExamCertificationTaker')->findOneBy(['user' => $user, 'module_group' => $module_group]);

        if ($exam_certif_taker) {
            $exam_certif_taker->setCompleted(new \DateTime());
            null == $exam_certif_taker->getTries() ? $exam_certif_taker->setTries(1) : $exam_certif_taker->setTries(2);
        } else {
            $exam_certif_taker = new ExamCertificationTaker();
            $exam_certif_taker->setExamTaker($exam_taker);
            $exam_certif_taker->setUser($user);
            $exam_certif_taker->setModuleGroup($module_group);
            $exam_certif_taker->setCompleted(new \DateTime());
            $exam_certif_taker->setTries(1);
            $em->persist($exam_certif_taker);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new Exam Taker.
     */
    public function createNewExamTaker($user, $module_group)
    {
        // get manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $exam_taker = new ExamTaker();
        $exam_taker->setUser($user);
        $exam_taker->setModuleGroup($module_group);
        $em->persist($exam_taker);
        $em->flush();

        return $exam_taker;
    }
}
```

The lines in the view with the retry input :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('user_exam_index', {'id': exam.moduleGroup.id}) }}">
                    <input type="submit" name="retry" class="waves-btn primary margin-top" value="Recommencer le quiz">
                </form>
```

the js function :

```
function initAjaxSaveExamAnswer(exam_taker_id, question_id) {

$('body').on('click', '.initAjaxSaveExamAnswer', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    // check if an answer is checked
    if (!$('input:radio[name="question"]:checked').val()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Tu dois choisir au moins une réponse !");
        return;
    }

    var answer_id = $('input:radio[name="question"]:checked').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Routing.generate('user_exam_save'),
        data: {exam_taker_id: exam_taker_id, question_id: question_id, answer_id: answer_id},
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        location.reload();
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Une erreur s\'est produite. Veuillez réessayer votre action...');
    });
});
```

}

**EDIT :**
Here is the process : i display the first question with radio button answers. Then I click on a button that launch the ajax function. The Ajax function check if the answer is correct or not and then calculate the next question to display or end the quiz if too many incorrect answers for example. In both cases, the ajax function return a `location.reload();`. The page is reloaded thanks to the indexAction() in the controller. When the quiz is ended, this is the results view that is displayed containing a form with the retry submit button. I click on the submit retry button in order to restart a new quiz. Then the indexAction() is called and return the new first question of the new quiz. A t the same moment, I remove the retry parameter. But I can see the Request Content is still containing somme info about the retry parameter. Maybe is that a clue ? Well the retry parameter is well removed at this time. But when I valid the first answer, the next question appears and the retry parameter is back in the request which is bad because the results view can never be displayed again because of this bad behaviour.

Comment: Please show your JS codes, and specify at which part you removing the "retry" parameter.

Comment: i tried to be more clear in my explanations...

Comment: Please also include the part that calls initAjaxSaveExamAnswer